# android live radio player setDataSource

Tags: java, android

Im following tutorials on youtube and I'm stuck https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPpVZ8YZXHk&t=62s

in the tutorial after entering

```
      package com.example.oneilbogle.radiov1;

  import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b_play;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

String stream = "http://142.4.217.133:8647/stream";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);


b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
}
class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);

        return prepared;
    }
  }
}
```

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);

the author uses a try/catch option but i get a different option [image: option1]

[image]

what should i do ?

Comment: Watch the tutorial and try to understand which of the proposed options you must choose.

Comment: @Rotwang     nonoe of these options are in the video

Comment: In the video you will see an option which is *similar* to the (more recent API Level feature) options you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing the parameters names around. 
Try with either:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);
        return prepared;
    }
```

or

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
        return prepared;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so what i did was i changed it to stream

```
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream);
```